# Show different views as a slideshow in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I am working on a health and monitoring dashboard with several views and want to show all views one by one as a slide show periodically.

```
<iframe src="http://jquery.com/" id="myFrame" width="500" marginwidth="0" height="500" marginheight="0" align="middle" scrolling="auto"></iframe>

    <script>
    setInterval(test, 10000);

    function test(){
    //setTimeout(loadPage1, 2000);

     setTimeout(loadPage2, 2000);

     setTimeout(loadPage3, 2000);
     }



        function loadPage1(){
            var loc = "http://www.w3schools.com/";
            document.getElementById('myFrame').setAttribute('src', loc);                   
        }

        function loadPage2(){
            var loc = "https://internalapplication/Controller/ActionName1";
            document.getElementById('myFrame').setAttribute('src', loc);
        }

        function loadPage3(){
            var loc = "https://internalapplication/Controller/ActionName2";
            document.getElementById('myFrame').setAttribute('src', loc);
        }

    </script>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/35s3m6ru/2/**

I am getting below error.

"**Refused to display 'https://internalapplication/Controller/ActionName1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'**".

Any help or advise will be highly appreciated.

Edit: updated code with relative URLS

**http://jsfiddle.net/35s3m6ru/6/**

Comment: Use relative urls and `controller/actioname` instead of viewname

Comment: Thanks Shyju. I have updated code with relative urls http://jsfiddle.net/35s3m6ru/6/.  See Index page is loading fine but iframe content is not refreshing with NotificationSummary/ErrorSummary content. My goal here is to display "Index" view for 20 secs, NotificationSummary and ErrorSummary 10 secs each and then repeat the whole process infinitely.

Comment: I think you would be better served using partial views and Ajax calls to load them than iframe.

Comment: @Speedbird186: Thank you. Loading partial views using Ajax solved my problem. I thought it will be easy to implement using iframe but I see many issues with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following method to your Global.asax.cs file

```
   protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
     {
     Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
     Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "AllowAll");
     }
```

This should solve the issue.